# Iterating a multiple of sine function makes a square wave

Tags: trigonometry, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

So, I found something curious playing around with a graphing calculator. Say we start with a function, $f_1(x) = 2\sin(x)$ and we define a constant, $C$,to be the positive fixed point for $f_1(x)$. Then we talk about the recurrence relation: $f_{n}(x) = f_1 \circ f_{n-1}(x)$. It seems to be the case that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{C}f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
  \phantom{-}1 & \text{if}\ \sin(x)>0 \\
  -1           & \text{if}\ \sin(x)<0
\end{cases} $$

I toyed with using numbers other than $2$ in this nesting procedure and they all either limit towards horrendous and strange shapes or tend towards being identically zero. Does anyone have any idea as to why this composition creates a square wave, and whether or not other "Fourier-Series" results like this can be found this way?

Comment: $C \approx 1.89549$ for the record.

Comment: What is $f$? Is this supposed to be $f_1$?

Comment: $f_1 = 2\sin(x)$ I added (x) to make it more clear I hope.

Comment: No $f$, like you defined $f_n= f \circ f_{n-1}$

Comment: Oh yeah! It is $f_1$

Comment: Oh ok, this is pretty cool

Comment: Iterating $f(x)=k\sin x$ leads to a square wave when $1<k<2.26183$. This is the range for which the fixed point $C$ is an [attractive fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)#Attractive_fixed_points), i.e. $|f'(C)|<1$.

Comment: Look up "dynamical systems" and "cobwebbing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Fourier series. You get a piecewise constant periodic function;  such functions are also popular examples in Fourier series textbooks; and that's all the connection there is.

Generally, the values of the limit $F(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ are fixed points of $f$, wherever the limit exists. Fixed points can be attracting ($|f'|<1$) or repelling ($|f'|>1$), or indifferent ($|f'|=1$, which is an edge case). Only a discrete set of points converge to a repelling fixed point, because to converge to it, one has to jump directly to that point. So, at almost all points where $F$ is defined, it will be equal to an attracting fixed point of $f$.

The function $f(x)=2\sin x$ has two attracting points, $\pm C$, and repelling fixed point $0$. Since its range is $[-2,2]$, it suffices to consider the behavior on this interval:

[image: 2sinx]

The positive part of the interval stays invariant (as a whole) under this function, and all points there shift toward the positive attracting point. Hence, $F(x)=C$ when $\sin x>0$. Similarly for the negative part.

As [Rahul observed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827436/strange-way-to-make-a-square-wave#comment3735337_1827436), this is not a special property of $2$; there is a range of factors $k$ in which $k\sin x$ has the same kind of dynamical behaviour.

In general, orbits don't need to converge to a fixed point at all; a common scenario is getting trapped within a loop between two or more intervals that get mapped to one another. This happens, for example, with the iteration of $f(x)=2\cos x$, which I [wrote about elsewhere](https://calculus7.org/2014/01/22/from-boring-to-puzzling-in-30-iterative-steps/).

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious, but it may be worth making explicit that the value of $C$ implied by the graph agrees with that asserted by the OP in a comment to their question.